# How to use "global static" variable in matlab function called in c

Tags: c++, matlab, global-variables, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Hi I'm currently coding in MATLAB and C. I have compiled MATLAB functions into a C shared library using [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/shared-libraries.html) (mcc), and called the functions in the shared library in a C++ program.

Can a global variable be declared to share data between MATLAB functions when called in C++?

To be exact, if there is a function `matlabA()` and function `matlabB()` in matlab, and is compiled into c++ shared library using mcc compiler as `cppA()` and `cppB()`, can I share a variable between them just by declaring variables as global in `matlabA()` and `matlabB()`?

It doesn't appear to work, then how can I share variable between functions?

Thanks!

#### MATLAB

```
function matlabA()
    global foo
    foo = 1;
end

function matlabB()
    global foo
    foo
end
```

#### C++

```
cppA();
cppB();
```

Comment: Thank you for your modification. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/06/19/writing-deployable-code/) by Loren Shure, it is strongly recommended not to use non-constant static variables (e.g. read/write globals) in deployed applications.

Instead you can create a [handle class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) to encapsulate the data, and explicitly pass the object to those functions (which has reference copy semantics).

Example:

#### FooData.m

```
classdef FooData < handle
    properties
        val
    end
end
```

#### fun_A.m

```
function foo = fun_A()
    foo = FooData();
    foo.val = 1;
end
```

#### fun_B.m

```
function fun_B(foo)
    disp(foo.val)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Originally I thought it would be too obscure for anybody to answer.

Comment: @SolessCHong: welcome to SO! I hope the proposed solution worked for you?

Comment: The idea really helped and I think the code is sure to work. However the program is actually more confiscated than shown above and it's my part time project, so it will take me some time to reconstruct the matlab code.

Comment: Hi I'll be more than grateful if you could check out this new thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747411/how-to-compile-matlab-class-into-c-lib