# How to compile Matlab class into C lib?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

The origin of this question is from here [How to use "global static" variable in matlab function called in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714825/how-to-use-global-static-variable-in-matlab-function-called-in-c).

I'm trying to encapsulate the "global variable" into an object. However I don't know how to export the matlab class to c++ using  [MATLAB Compiler (mcc)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/shared-libraries.html)

To do this I just tried the standard command

#### Matlab Command

```
mcc -W cpplib:Vowel4 -T link:lib Vowel4.m
```

#### Matlab Script

```
classdef Vowel4

  properties
    x
    y
  end

  methods
    Vowel4
    A
    B
  end

end
```

The generated lib is actually stand-alone functions rather than c++ class.

How can I compile classes in Matlab into c++ classes?

I've been searching for an answer but didn't find one.

Obviously the matlab command is not suitable for this scenario. However I cannot find any information on building Matlab classes into c++ classes.

========================== Edit ========================

The actual cpp code is as follows: @Alan

```
mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0);
loadDataInitialize();
soundByCoefInitialize();
loadData(); 

mwArray F(4, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
float test[4];

for ( ;; ){
    const Frame frame = controller.frame();
    const FingerList fingers = frame.fingers();
    if ( !fingers.empty() ){
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i ++ ){
            double v = fingers.count() > i ? (fingers[i].tipPosition().y / 50) - 2 : 0;
            F(i+1,1) = v;
            test[i] = v;
            cout << v << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
        soundByCoef(F);
    }
}
```

Here the matlabA() corresponds to the loadData(), which loads the data, and soundByCoef(F) corresponds to the matlabB(), which do the job in the main loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by Alan, [I was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718438/97160) only suggesting using handle class as a container for your global variables (with the benefit that such an object would be passed by reference). The created object is not intended to be directly manipulated by your C++ code (it will be stored in the generic `mxArray/mwArray` C/C++ struct).

[As far](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30EZVF/) as [I know](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246759), you cannot directly compile classdef-style MATLAB classes into proper C++ classes when building shared libraries using the MATLAB Compiler. It only supports building regular functions. You could create functional interfaces to MATLAB class member methods, but that's a different story...

Perhaps a complete example would help illustrate the idea I had in mind. First lets define the code on the MATLAB side:

#### GlobalData.m

This is the handle class used to store the global vars.

```
classdef GlobalData < handle
    %GLOBALDATA  Handle class to encapsulate all global state data.
    %
    % Note that we are not taking advantage of any object-oriented programming
    % concept in this code. This class acts only as a container for publicly
    % accessible properties for the otherwise global variables.
    %
    % To manipulate these globals from C++, you should create the class API
    % as normal MATLAB functions to be compiled and exposed as regular C
    % functions by the shared library.
    % For example: create(), get(), set(), ...
    %
    % The reason we use a handle-class instead of regular variables/structs
    % is that handle-class objects get passed by reference.
    %

    properties
        val
    end
end
```

#### create_globals.m

A wrapper function that acts as a constructor to the above class

```
function globals = create_globals()
    %CREATE_GLOBALS  Instantiate and return global state

    globals = GlobalData();
    globals.val = 2;
end
```

#### fcn_add.m, fcn_times.m

MATLAB functions to be exposed as C++ functions

```
function out = fcn_add(globals, in)
    % receives array, and return "input+val" (where val is global)

    out = in + globals.val;
end

function out = fcn_times(globals, in)
    % receives array, and return "input*val" (where val is global)

    out = in .* globals.val;
end
```

With the above files stored in current directory, lets build the C++ shared library using the MATLAB Compiler:

```
>> mkdir out
>> mcc -W cpplib:libfoo -T link:lib -N -v -d ./out create_globals.m fcn_add.m fcn_times.m
```

You should expect the following generated files among others (I'm on a Windows machine):

```
./out/libfoo.h
./out/libfoo.dll
./out/libfoo.lib
```

Next, we could create a sample C++ program to test the library:

#### main.cpp

```
// Sample program that calls a C++ shared library created using
// the MATLAB Compiler.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// include library header generated by MATLAB Compiler
#include "libfoo.h"

int run_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // initialize MCR
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0)) {
        cerr << "Failed to init MCR" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // initialize our library
    if( !libfooInitialize() ) {
        cerr << "Failed to init library" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        // create global variables
        mwArray globals;
        create_globals(1, globals);

        // create input array
        double data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        mwArray in(3, 3, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        in.SetData(data, 9);

        // create output array, and call library functions
        mwArray out;
        fcn_add(1, out, globals, in);
        cout << "Added matrix:\n" << out << endl;
        fcn_times(1, out, globals, in);
        cout << "Multiplied matrix:\n" << out << endl;
    } catch (const mwException& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // destruct our library
    libfooTerminate();

    // shutdown MCR
    mclTerminateApplication();

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    mclmcrInitialize();
    return mclRunMain((mclMainFcnType)run_main, 0, NULL);
}
```

Lets build the standalone program:

```
>> mbuild -I./out main.cpp ./out/libfoo.lib -outdir ./out
```

And finally run the executable:

```
>> cd out
>> !main
Added matrix: 
     3     6     9 
     4     7    10 
     5     8    11 
Multiplied matrix: 
     2     8    14 
     4    10    16 
     6    12    18
```

HTH

Comment: You are really helpful and warm hearted and I really appreciate your effort devoted in answering my question. And my apology for not understanding why you suggest using a handle class. I thought you were suggesting using a class to share variable between member functions. I think the misunderstanding comes from my improficiency in using classes in Matlab.

Comment: @SolessCHong: no worries. Seeing your code, I think the above approach should work for you: replace `create_globals()` with the `loadData()` function which reads data from disk, stores it in the handle class instance and returns that object. Any other functions that needs to access this data (e.g `soundByCoef()`) should also be passed the previous object in addition to its usual input arguments. The data will be stored in MATLAB's managed memory, and no copying will be performed when passing the data around, so there shouldn't be too much overhead I think.

Comment: Couldn't get it running in C#, create_globals() returns a null NWArray. Any ideas? I expect it to be similar but somethings wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the thread in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714825/how-to-use-global-static-variable-in-matlab-function-called-in-c), the suggestion wasn't to wrap your functions in a class, but rather to use a class to pass about the global variable which compiling leaves you unable to use.

```
classdef Foo < handle
  properties
    value
  end

  methods
    function obj = Foo(value)
      obj.value = value;
    end
  end
end
```

Note: the class Foo extends the `handle` class in order to make it pass by reference, rather than pass by value. See: [the comparison between handle and value classes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).

```
function foo = matlabA()
  foo = new Foo(1);
end

function matlabB(foo)
  foo.value
end
```

As far as I know, the matlab compiler doesn't compile the code as such, but rather [packages it with a copy of the MATLAB Component Runtime](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/06/19/writing-deployable-code/) and writes some wrapper functions to handle invoking said runtime on the code from c/c++.

I would recommend avoiding jumping back and forth between matlab and c/c++ too much; there is bound to be some overhead to converting the datatypes and invoking the MCR.  All I really use it for is wrapping up a complex but self-contained matlab script (i.e.: doesn't need to interact with the c/c++ code mid way through said script) as a function, or packaging up code for deployment to environments which don't have a full copy of matlab.

**As an interesting side note: if you are calling C++ from within Matlab**, and that C++ code needs access to a global variable, things are much easier. You can simply do this by wrapping your C++ code into a [mexFunction](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html) and compiling that. In the places you need to access a variable which is in the Matlab workspace, you can do so using the [mexGetVariablePtr](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/apiref/mexgetvariableptr.html) which will return a read-only pointer to the data. The variable you are accessing can be in either the global workspace, or that of the function which called your mexFunction.

With this approach I would suggest liberally comment the variable that you are getting in both the C++ and Matlab code, as the link between them may not be obvious from the Matlab side; you wouldn't want someone to come along later, edit the script and wonder why it had broken.

**In this case it seems that the C++ side doesn't really need access to the data**, so you could refactor it to have matlab do the calling by wrapping the "get current position of fingers" code into a mexFunction, then have matlab do the loop:

```
data = loadData();
while(~stop) {
  position = getFingerPositionMex();
  soundByCoef(position, data);
}
```

Assuming you don't modify the data within `soundByCoef` Matlab will use pass by reference, so there will be no copying of the large dataset.

Comment: Actually in my application, I'm using [Leapmotion](http://leapmotion.com) c++ sdk in a matlab sound producing script. And I've to read huge data from disk. So matlabA() is to load the data and in the application I just call matlabB() in the main loop without loading data over and over again. This is why I'm trying to declare global variable.

Comment: Wait, wait! You are saying that you are running this **in Matlab**? That is: matlab script calls C++ code, which in turn calls more matlab to get some data? *goes to edit answer to account for this*

Comment: No. Calling matlab function in C++. Also it's a good idea to consider calling c++ sdk for Leap in Matlab. However it's not the case here.

Comment: If you are still having problems with this, can you provide some more context about your project?

Comment: Thanks. It seems this boils down to having a bunch of data which needs to be persistent on the Matlab side, so I think the handle class method is your best bet. We can't just use globals because if we were to call this function in two threads they would interfere; so using the handle class approach will let you store the data in the matlab memory space while having a reference to it for the particular instance of the function.

Comment: Yeah. The handle should be the best choice. Thx