# How can transfer data between "mwArray *" and "mxArray *"?

Tags: c++, matlab, wrapper, mex, mcc

I have an instance of a class and I want to pass it to a function using `mexCallMATLAB` function.

The class is originally in Matlab but since the data is in my C++ wrapper, I used this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747411/how-to-compile-matlab-class-into-c-lib) and pack my data to it. Therefore type of final object is `mwArray` (look mentioned link and `GlobalData` class which is in Matlab and `globals` instance which is in C++). But `mexCallMATLAB` function uses `mxArray *`.

How can transfer data of a  `mwArray *` to `mwArray *`? If the types was simple it can easy done with manual transferring. For example creating a double array of `mxArray` and manually copy the data to it. But in this situation the data is a class of multiple data fields/type.

More generally how can pass a class to a Matlab function from C++ wrapper?

Suppose this is the class in Matlab

```
classdef GlobalData < handle

    properties
        val1
        val2
        val3
    end
end
```

This is the Matlab function that I compiled via `mcc` and used for wrap the class.

```
function globals = create_globals()

    globals = GlobalData();
    globals.val1 = 2;
    globals.val2 = 5.25;
    globals.val3 = 'data name';
end
```

This is the C++ code that has the data. Here we use the previous method to create a instance of GlobalData and the pass it to Matlab function `myCallback`.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    // ...
    mwArray globals;
        try {

            // Pack data to a single Container class of type GlobalData
            create_globals(1, globals);

        } catch (const mwException& e) {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            return;
        } catch (...) {
            cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << endl;
            return;
        }

        int nlhs1 = 1, nrhs1 = 2;
        mxArray *plhs1[1], *prhs1[2];

        // First parameter of myCallback set to a arbitrary double value
        prhs1[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
        *mxGetPr(prhs1[0]) = .6;

        // Here prhs1[1] must set to globals
        // ??? prhs1[1] = globals ???

        mexCallMATLAB(nlhs1, plhs1, nrhs1, prhs1, "myCallback");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please show you code. I am not psychic.

Comment: Is this a typo _"How can convert a  mwArray * to mwArray *?"_  ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I mean how can copy a mwArray to mxArray when type of mwArray is a class not simple data type like `int` or `double`.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj code added.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `mxArray *` by using the `GetData()` method.

```
   mwArray *A;
   mxArray *B;

   B = A->GetData();
```

Comment: `GetData` method takes two input. `buffer` and `size`. Therefore `B = A->GetData();` must change to `A->GetData(B, sizeof(A));` But this code gets `cannot
convert argument 1 from 'mxArray *' to 'mxDouble *'`